# Difference between varchar(10) and varchar ( 10 char) in sqlplus

Tags: mysql, sqlplus

What is the difference between them ?
Specifically, how does the storage differ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is:

- `varchar(10 CHAR)` is static and will use always 10 spaces.
- `varchar(10)` is dynamic and will only use the space he needs.

I use `varchar(x)` almost in all cases. If you are sure a cell is has always the same amount of charachters you could use `varchar(x CHAR)`.